# Is the JCache API (JSR 107) part of Java EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, caching, jcache

Been googling for a long time and can't seen to find any information on this.

I'm not 100% sure if it is part of the Java EE platform but my gut feeling it is not. Although, it seems most Java EE compliant application containers do use/ or allow usage of caching systems.

Is it part of Java SE?

Or is it just a standalone specification?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-jcache-jsr-107: "JCache support is required for Java EE 7.". 1 minute ...

Comment: according to this link it seems not be a official part of JEE 7 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is the JCache API (JSR 107) part of Java EE?

The short answer is *no*.

---

The Java Temporary Caching API (`javax.cache` package) is not included in the Java EE 7 API [dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you need the Java Temporary Caching API, you need another [dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.cache/cache-api/1.0.0):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

In a similar way, the JSR 107 is not included in the [Java EE 7 technologies list](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index-jsp-142185.html).

And Java Temporary Caching API final version [announcement](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/jcache_is_final_i_repeat) mentions the following:

> It should be possible to use it as a **drop-in addition to a Java EE 6 or Java EE 7 application**. Although JCache does not specifically address Java EE integration most common use cases should be supported, including a pretty cool set of caching annotations that work with CDI.

---

The Java Temporary Caching API is not part of the [Java EE 8 technologies](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/java-ee-8-3890673.html) either.

Answer (score 1):

According to Oracle it is needed for Java EE and needs to be in the Web Profile:

https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/java_ee_7_key_features

Comment: That links mentions "possible inclusion" of JCache; however it's not listed on Oracle's list of Java EE 7 technologies at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html.