# Does Spring Framework 6.x support Jcache (JSR 107) implementation (javax.cache:cache-api:1.1.1)?

Tags: spring, gradle, jcache, jakarta-migration

I'm looking to make an upgrade to a Spring backend project, moving from Spring 5.3 to Spring 6.1. Since this upgrade requires migrating from Javax to a Jakarta namespace, I was looking into some of the dependencies of this project.

At the moment, Jcache (javax.cache:cache-api:1.1.1) and Ehcache (org.ehcache:ehcache:3.10.0) are being used to handle the caching for the project and is setup within a @Configuration class using the javax CacheManager.

**What I'm trying to determine** is whether the current gradle dependency (javax.cache:cache-api:1.1.1) is usable within Spring Framework 6.1.1, or if I need to update/replace this and implement Jcache differently. Any insight would be appreciated!

Since Jcache is Javax based, I tried researching to see if it was compatible with Spring 6.1 and Jakarta EE, as I know some Javax packages are still available for use on Jakarta platforms. However, it doesn't seem very clear to me, as a lot of articles I have read talk about the Spring Boot Cache dependency, however this project is not implementing Spring Boot. I also searched the Spring Docs, and I see mention of JSR 107 support, but nothing about this specific dependency implementation (javax.cache:cache-api).

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen (source [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ehcache/ehcache/3.10.8)), EhCache has runtime dependency of `jaxb-runtime` 2.x which is `javax` based.

`javax.cache:cache-api` itself depends (optional) of the `javax.entreprise:cdi-api` but since this dependency is optional it shouldn't be a problem.

My guess is you should switch to another cache system if using ehcache.
I personnaly use [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), and they talk about JSR107 / JCache in their [wiki](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/JCache)

**EDIT based on comment (thanks to redheaddev)**

Ehcache variant with `jakarta` classifier exists from version 3.10.
With this classifier, it depends on jaxb jakarta-based version, so a simple update should do the trick if application does not depend on `cdi-api`.

Comment: Thankfully it looks like Ehcache, as of version 3.10, has compatibility for the Jakarta version of jaxb ([Source](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/releases/tag/v3.10.0)), it just needs to be specified when listing it as a dependency.

I did a bit more digging and it seems like the javax.cache package isn't actually part of the Java EE technologies ([Stack Overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278769/is-the-jcache-api-jsr-107-part-of-java-ee)), so on first glance, it seems like this current Jcache implementation may work fine, so long as I include jakarta capability.

Comment: Good to know this classifier option. Hope it'll work for you. Edited answer to point that out